# Expression pour l'acte d'y penser encore

Tags: expressions, expressions-idiomatiques

Disons que j'ai regardé un film captivant. Cela fait des heures que je l'ai vu mais j'y pense encore. Quelles expressions je peux utiliser pour exprimer cette situation ?

Comment: J'y réfléchis longuement, je le retourne dans ma tête, j'ai de quoi m'occuper, peut-être ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On peut dire :
je n'arrive pas à me le sortir de la tête ! (j'y pense tout le temps) 
Ou plus prégnant, prenant tout l'espace mental :
Je continue d'être envahi par ce film.

Answer (score 1):

Voici un exemple : Ce film m'a laissé une très forte impression.

Answer (score 0):

On peut dire, par exemple (langage courant):
"Ce film m'a marqué, j'y pense encore".

Comment: Cela ne répond pas à la question posée.